# how to get self.frame X-axis

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

How to get UIView frame's X-axis
I just can get center's x-axis like

```
self.center.x
```

then how to get UIView frame's x-axis
this UIView can moved,i want in moving get frame's x.
Thank you

Comment: I guess at least some of the 'get'´s should be 'set'. You question doesn't make sense to me this way. Could you please review?

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
yourView.frame.origin.x = //to any int/float value
```

With this you will be able to move your view through the x axis

Good Luck

Answer (score 1):

If self is UIView then you can read self.frame.origin.x;

To write:
CGRect myFrame = self.frame;
myFrame.origin.x = //whatever X coordinate
self.frame = myFrame;